# Translating between complex blow-up and symplectic cut

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

[Symplectic cutting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_cut) is a way of describing a symplectic form on the blow-up $\tilde M$ of a complex manifold $M$, if we have a symplectic form on $M$ (that is compatible with the complex structure). Unfortunately, with symplectic cutting, it is not easy to lift holomorphic curves to the blow-up. In the book by McDuff-Salamon, this operation is performed in the case of the blow-up of a point, assuming that there is a standard complex structure (with respect to a Darboux chart) in the neighbourhood of the blow-up point. If we do not have such a complex structure, can we at least say the following: for a holomorphic curve $C$ in the complex blow-up, there is a symplectic representative of the homology class $[C]$. This looks very plausible, but I am having trouble coming up with a neat proof. Any inputs are welcome.